# Shell Script: passing variable to spark-shell session

Tags: bash, shell, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sh

I'm trying to pass a variable to a spark-shell session. Essentially my goal is to create a code that will read a text file line by line and execute SQL queries one by one present in the text file. To do this, I need to be able to pass the value of "p" into the spark session. But I'm not able to do so:

```
#!/bin/bash
export p="SELECT distinct year, period FROM calendar "
export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2
spark-shell << 'EOF'
spark.sql(${p}).show(100, false)
:quit
EOF
```

The above code gets me the following error:

```
scala> spark.sql(${p}).show(100, false)
<console>:24: error: not found: value $
       spark.sql(${p}).show(100, false)
                 ^
<console>:24: error: not found: value p
       spark.sql(${p}).show(100, false)
                   ^

scala> :quit
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write: `spark-shell << 'EOF'`, you are explicitly telling the shell not to interpolate variables in the heredoc.  Drop the quotes and write:

```
spark-shell << EOF
```